# How to make sh-set-shell insert "#!/bin/sh" instead of "#!/usr/bin/sh"

Tags: shell-mode

When I open a shell script (e.g. `emacs myscript.sh`) and do `C-c :` (`M-x sh-set-shell`), and select `sh` as the shell, Emacs will insert a `#!/usr/bin/sh` shebang instead of `#!/bin/sh`. I want Emacs to insert `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/usr/bin/sh`. I realize that Emacs is probably behaving like this because `/usr/bin` comes before `/bin` in my shell's `PATH`. What are some ways to prioritize the `/bin` directory only when running `sh-set-shell`?

Comment: `sh-set-shell` allows you to just say `/bin/sh`, and it will use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an advice around `sh-set-shell` will do.

```lisp
(defun sh-set-shell-tmp-path-advice (func &rest r)
  "Wrap `sh-set-shell' with temporarily modified
`exec-path'."
  (let ((exec-path (cons "/bin/" exec-path)))
    (apply func r)))

(advice-add 'sh-set-shell
            :around 'sh-set-shell-tmp-path-advice)
```